# Evaluation of Real Integral (with pole) using Complex

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

For research, I’m attempting to solve this real integral through the use of complex   variables. I’m stuck on the approach of the actual integration because the pole lies on the   real axis. I started evaluating it using the Residue Theorem… however, I feel I may have to   use an ‘annulus’ approach to compute the real integral instead. Could someone help walk me   through the integration?

The variables '$w_c$' and 'a' are constants.

Also: if anyone has a suggestion for a different approach, I would love to hear it.

$$ f= {1\over \pi^2 w_c a}\int_0^{2\pi\over a} {k^2\over (1-{k^2a^2\over32})} dk $$

**Known so far**:
-Long Division expansion of the integral:

$$ f = {1\over \pi^2 w_c a} \left(\int_0^{2\pi\over a} {-32^2\over a^2(a^2k^2-32)} dk - \int_0^{2\pi\over a} {32\over a^2} dk\right) $$

- simple pole on the first integrand at ${4\sqrt{2} \over a}$
- the second integrand has no poles: can be solved without the use of complex.

Thanks for the help and the advice!

Comment: You seem to have not actually done any partial fractions, all that looks like has been done here is long division on the integrand. If you actually do the partial fractions you'll be in a better place.

Comment: Adam: thank you, I meant to write long division. Partial fraction is my next plan of attack. Thanks for pointing that error out for me.

Comment: @Caitlin I think you want to use the @ symbol when talking to someone (like on twitter). In my naive experience, contour integration is used in place of real integrals when they are too hard to compute directly, i.e. integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, or integrands with many exponentials intermixed. Something, like this which has an anti-derivative should probably be computed directly, i.e. $$\int \frac{1}{k^2-1} = \int \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(k-1)+\ln(k+1)).$$